# dual wallet confusion

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Newbie mistake. I created a view-only wallet from within a spend wallet (Ledger enabled) and gave it the same password as the spend wallet. Now both wallets appear under the view-only name and the password won't open either. So should I trash both wallets and recover 'a wallet' using my Ledger seed?  I tried to recover from the failed password prompt but the seed failed the Electrum verification screen? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: " I tried to recover from the failed password prompt but the seed failed the Electrum verification screen? " <= Did you enter your 24 word Ledger mnemonic seed into the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Before scrapping those wallets, change one (or, maybe better, both) of their names to something different.  Once they have different names, try to open again.

Comment: Easy solution.  Thank you very much.  Both wallets now open with the same password.  Just needed different names